# Both [fedex-api] and [fedex-shipping] have been shipped by [fedex]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

I believe these 3 tags need to be merged. There is no difference in meaning between the tags. fedex has a decent tag wiki and should be the main tag, since it's shortest and I don't see the need for other fedex-related tags here.

[fedex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedex)
[fedex-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedex-api)
[fedex-shipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedex-shipping)

Tag synonyms? Just plain merge? Thoughts?

Comment: Just merging all into fedex might be better.

Comment: @Deduplicator inb4 why is my package still in Menphis?

Comment: “Packing up the [fedex] tags”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [two new tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&search=fedex) that map [fedex-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedex-api) and [fedex-shipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedex-shipping) to [fedex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fedex).

They were both created yesterday by Robert Harvey.